# Apache camel FTP how can we know that all the files are downloaded from the FTP URL

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

Currently am working with Apache Camel FTP, How to know that all the folders of the accessed FTP URL are downloaded successfully? As I have all zip files on the FTP URL to download, I want to unzip them once the download is complete, but am not understanding when to unzip them as I don't know the downloading of all the .zip files is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Got Answer!!

```
      from("{{ftp.server}}")
        .to("file:target/download")
        .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.")
          .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
             boolean isComplete  = (Boolean)exchange.getProperties().get("CamelBatchComplete");
             });
```

isComplete will return you true else false, if all the files are downloaded/consumed.